# Confused why these are not spam

Tags: discussion, spam

[Are there open source gesture libraries in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120499/is-there-any-open-source-gesture-libraries-in-android/23048305#23048305)

[How to implement a "Two Finger Drag" gesture on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818530/how-to-implement-a-two-finger-drag-gesture-on-android/23048389#23048389)

Spam flags on these (identical at the time I flagged them) answers were declined.  I do not understand why.

Comment: What about these answers makes you think they are spam?

Comment: *"Ok been completely dumb and forgot to link the project"* ... twice @bluefeet ... not really spam, but spammy at the very least.

Comment: "This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional"  They don't attempt to answer the question they just say 'checkout my project'.

Comment: @Bart I didn't proceed the flags, but I would have declined spam flags on those answers.  They aren't spam.

Comment: @tcaswell It *does* disclose that it his his project.  it is arguably useful, it is relevant to the question, and it *does* attempt to answer the question.  That's 1 out of 5.  It is somewhat promotional, yes, which is something to be concerned with, but it doesn't *automatically* make it spam.

Comment: Don't disagree with the decision @bluefeet, but it's rather promotional and smelly, so I can forgive the confusion.

Comment: @tcaswell Spam flags have severe penalties to users, we use caution when marking those as valid - in this case neither one of them are spam.

Comment: @Servy I was also reacting to the fact that there were two identical answers posted at more-or-less the same time.  I will adjust my spam threshold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the description that accompanies the spam flag:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

Those posts do contain disclosure, and while I can't say how useful the linked project is, it does seem to be relevant to the questions being asked. One of the questions was off-topic, so it could have been flagged, but the two answers you flagged are not spam (as we define it).

Comment: Not only are they relevant, they are also useful for the particular problem in the question. It's easier to use and credit someone else's work on an appropriate license than to cook up your own solution. The fact that the poster is the author of the referenced library does not automatically make the post spam.

Answer (score 17):

Because they're answers to the questions (arguably poor quality answers, but that doesn't make them spam), rather than links to how to get your hands on cheap Viagra or real Guuci bags.

Comment: @ShadowWizard.  Apparently you didn't get the joke.

Comment: True,  looks like innocent typo.

Comment: @Servy are they discounted Guuci handbags?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Of course not.  Nobody wants to buy cheap knockoffs.  These are the Genuine Guuci bags that nobody else sells.

Comment: If the question is "How can I get my hands on cheap Viagra?", is it still spam to post links to do exactly that?